# Closed but not exact differential forms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-forms

I'm studying differential forms and have two questions about them.

1) I'm stuck with the following task given by my teacher: give an example of closed but not exact 1-form defined on $\Omega = \Bbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(at, bt, (a + b)t): t \in \Bbb{R}\}$ where both $a$ and $b$ are fixed.

I already know the proposition that differential 1-form $\omega$ is not exact if there are such closed curve $\Gamma: \oint_{\Gamma}\omega \neq 0$. But how can i find such differential form ?

2) And also I want to know if there any closed but not exact 2-forms on $\Omega$?

Comment: Is that $\Bbb R^3$ minus a line?

Comment: @AnginaSeng yes

Comment: Then can you do it for $\Bbb R^3$ minus the $z$-axis?

Comment: @AnginaSeng something like $\frac{-ydx + x dy}{x^2 + y^2}$ ?

Comment: Good, now can you transform that to work for your line instead?

Comment: @AnginaSeng thank you, i got it. Can you help me with my second question ?

Comment: You do not mean $\oint_\Gamma d\omega$, of course. For your second homework question, it's very hard for us to know what you know and what you do not know. What have you tried?

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, I edited the question

Comment: Problem two is deep and you would need to know much more to answer it.

Comment: @AnginaSeng does my 1-form from my previous comment works for my line ? Looks like everything is fine